# Connecting a headless Pi Zero W to a bluetooth speaker

Tags: bluetooth, headless, pulseaudio

Edit: The problem does not occur using another bluetooth speaker. As that speaker is also the one I'm planning on using, the question is now only of academic interest.

I'm trying to set up a small music streaming box using mopidy on a raspi zero w.

Currently I'm stuck trying to get my bluetooth speaker connected and staying connected.
What I'm doing so far (completely from the beginning, just in case):

Write the raspbian lite image to a micro-sd card.

Add

```
enable_uart=1
force_turbo=1
```

options to config.txt

Boot the pi connected to a serial adapter and do basic setup:

edit wpa_supplicant.conf with my wifi settings,

enable ssh, set the hostname, timezone, wifi region using and expand the filesystem using raspi-config

reboot & connect via ssh

since bluez5 doesn't do ALSA, I need pulseaudio

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

to get pulseaudio a working dbus i start a session:

```
dbus-run-session bash
```

in there I start pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio -D -vvvv
```

and try to connect to the speaker

```
bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:D1:6F:E7 discopi [default]
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller B8:27:EB:D1:6F:E7 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 X-SMC01
[bluetooth]# pair B8:69:C2:17:89:50
Attempting to pair with B8:69:C2:17:89:50
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 UUIDs:
        0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 UUIDs:
        0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
        0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust B8:69:C2:17:89:50
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Trusted: yes
Changing B8:69:C2:17:89:50 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect B8:69:C2:17:89:50
Attempting to connect to B8:69:C2:17:89:50
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device B8:69:C2:17:89:50 Connected: no
```

I get a connection, but a few seconds later it drops again.

I've got a metric ton of logs (available [here](http://pastebin.com/KZnCKL5N) ), as bluetoothd is debug-logging as well but one line seems strange to me:

```
Mar 12 13:44:52 discopi pulseaudio[771]: Could not set format on sink bluez_sink.B8_69_C2_17_89_50
```

While the speaker is connected i see a sink in pulseaudio, but trying to play to it just yields silence.

I'm kind of helpless at the moment.

Comment: just curious which Bluetooth speaker you have working with the Pi W? Thanks! Jase

Comment: I got it working with a BOSE Soundlink Mini 2