# Connecting to Bluetooth speaker only works in X, not in terminal

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I am running pulseaudio -D to start pulseaudio as a daemon, then running sudo bluetoothctl, connect  to connect to the bluetooth speaker (it has already been paired). When I do this in X11 with a screen attached, it works fine, but when I do it in the terminal, it doesn't. I get the seemingly common error "Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed".

I get the same results as the post here: [Connecting a headless Pi Zero W to a bluetooth speaker](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63226/connecting-a-headless-pi-zero-w-to-a-bluetooth-speaker) when pairing to it for the first time - it pairs, then connects for a small amount of time, then disconnects, and gives the org.bluez.Error.Failed any time I try to connect after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!